# happens not to target resources in a folder with fileURLWithPath

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have a concern with this method :

```
NSURL.fileURLWithPath (NSBundle.mainBundle.bundlePath)
```

until the the works well but I would like to resouces that my method looks for me in the pages folder.

I did something like this:

```
NSURL.fileURLWithPath (NSBundle.mainBundle.bundlePath + 'page/')
```

but its not working,
therefore I do not see how I could use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this NSBundle method

```
URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:
```

Returns the file URL for the resource file identified by the specified name and extension and residing in a given bundle directory.

- (NSURL *)URLForResource:(NSString *)name withExtension:(NSString *)extension subdirectory:(NSString *)subpath

or any other in NSBundle, there are method for returning array of URLs in subdirectory of you want to iterate them for example.